# iOS - table view error

Tags: ios, uitableview

i've a little problem with my first table view, i'm using an example taken from internet but when i run the code, it crash saying:

```
2011-09-15 15:58:48.873 fptNew[1710:207] -[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b3d120
2011-09-15 15:58:48.876 fptNew[1710:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b3d120'
```

here is the code:

```
//  familySelect.m
//  fptNew
//
//  Created by Marco on 14/09/11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.

#import "familySelect.h"

@implementation familySelect

@synthesize colorNames;

 // The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
/*
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization.
    }
    return self;
}
*/


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"eseguito");
    self.colorNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Red", @"Green", @"Blue", @"Indigo", @"Violet", nil];

    //UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:111];
    //label.backgroundColor =   [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2f green:0.3f blue:0.4f alpha:0.00000f];

}



- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Overriden to allow any orientation.
    return YES;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}


- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.colorNames count];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.colorNames objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];

    return cell;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

here is the .h file:

```
//  familySelect.h
//  fptNew
//
//  Created by Marco on 14/09/11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface familySelect : UIViewController 
    <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    NSArray *colorNames;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *colorNames;

@end
```

and in the .xib file i've set the table view dataSource and delegato to the File's Owner (familySelect)

don't understand where is the problem, thanks for any help

Comment: Is the file's owner your "familySelect" type?  I only ask since it says in the error that UIViewController doesn't support that selector, which is true, however your "familySelect" type should.

Comment: And did you connect datasource and delegate of table with file's owner?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to make the following connections within Interface Builder

- table to File's Owner (select delegate)
- table to File's Owner (select datasource)
- File's Owner to view (select view) : this connection is made automatically
- File's Owner to table (select tableView)

See [also this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW10)

Comment: thanks you, done but still doesn't work, but the error has changed

Answer (score 3):

Where is your IBOutlet UITableView* myTableView ?

Comment: added and connected, thanks, but still not working, now the error say:

thank you for your answer, i've declared the a UITableView in the .h file in this way:

IBOutlet UITableView0 *tableView;

and connecter the File's Owner view and File's Owner table to the tableView, now the error has changed and say:

2011-09-15 17:00:30.242 fptNew[1927:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x4e55470> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableView.'

Comment: have you connected your tableView in Interface builder ?

Comment: this error comes when in something went wrong with InterfaceBuilder.. goto ViewController.. right click on it.. delete with yellow exclamation marks

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have passed the Tableview's method on the View Controller and hence crashing.

```
 -[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]
```

You have connected the View for the VIew Controller to the TableView. Instead, declare a UITableView and connect this tableview over there.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i've declared the a UITableView in the .h file in this way:

IBOutlet UITableView0 *tableView;

and connecter the File's Owner view and File's Owner table to the tableView, now the error has changed and say:

2011-09-15 17:00:30.242 fptNew[1927:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x4e55470> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableView.'

Comment: did you connect the View for the ViewController to the UIVIew in the Xib file?